# Combine Alias with new arguments

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

How can I combine an alias command and a new argument to execute?

I have defined
`alias sqME="squeue -u abcdef123456789"`. However, sometimes I want to execute
`squeue -u abcdef123456789 -start`, which I try to abbreviate by `sqME -start`, which does not work. (This example is a SLURM scheduler query).

So how can I combine a alias with a new argument?

Comment: It should work. Please provide exact input and output of the commands you try to run, both with alias and normal (please edit post to include this).

Comment: maybe you will need to add a space at the end of this alias `alias sqME='squeue -u abcdef123456789 '`?

Comment: If it *didn't* work, then everyday commands like `ls -l` and almost anything involving `grep` would fail in bash - since those are aliased in the default `~/.bashrc` file